# My module producing sound could not be compiled

Tags: sound

So, here's my code to return a play object after passing in frequency and duration as parameters. When I run it, it says

> "Sound::ssnm: A good PlayRange could not be found since most of the
>   samples are not evaluating to machine-sized real numbers."

And I really couldn't understand why after thinking for a really long time... Am I missing something? When I don't use module and directly generate play objects, the body of codes works fine...

```
 ADSR[t_, Ta_, Td_, Ts_, Tr_, Aa_, Ad_] := Module[{ma, md, mr},
   ma = Aa/Ta;
   md = (Aa - Ad)/(Ta - Td);
   mr = Ad/(Ts - Tr);
   If[t <= Ta, Return[Aa ( 1 - Sqrt[1 - (t/Ta)^2])], Null];
   If [t <= Td, Return[Aa + md (t - Ta)], Null];
   If [t <= Ts, Return[Ad], Null];
   If [t <= Tr, Return[Ad (1 - Sqrt[1 - ((t - Tr)/(Tr - Ts))^2])], 
    Return[0.]];
   ]; (*This is the new adsr envelope used in AM*)


MySound[k_, dur_] := 
 Module[{fundamental, carrier, chromaticOvertones, amplitudes, 
   mA, s, sound},
  fundamental = 440*2^(k/12);
  carrier = fundamental;
  chromaticOvertones = Table[2^(i/12), {i, 0, 12}]；
  amplitudes = Table[1/E^i, {i, 1, Length[chromaticOvertones]}];
  mA[t_] = 
   Sum[amplitudes[[j]]*
     Sin[2*t*Pi*fundamental*chromaticOvertones[[j]]], {j, 1, 
     Length[chromaticOvertones]}];
  (*the amplitude of modulating signal in FM*)

  s[t_] := ADSR[t, .05, .1, .2, 1.5, 1.0, 0.7]*
    Sin[2*Pi*carrier*t + 
      mA[t, fundamental]*Cos[2*Pi*t*1.5 fundamental]*1/3];
  sound = Play[s[t, 440], {t, 0, dur}, SampleRate -> 8000];
  Return[sound];
  ]
p = MySound[1, .125]
EmitSound[p]
```

Here's the output from the kernel. And I don't understand it.

```
{； Return[
   Sound[SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(1/12)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(1/6)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(1/4)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(1/3)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(5/12)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], Sqrt[2] ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(7/12)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(2/3)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(3/4)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(5/6)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], (2^(11/12)) ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]], 2 ； 
  Return[Sound[
    SampledSoundFunction[
     Function[{Play`Time17}, 
      Block[{t = 
         0. + 0.000125 Play`Time17}, (s$181163[t, 440] + 0.) 1.]], 
     1000, 8000]]]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following changes eliminate the error messages. In the MySound function definition:

- Change `mA[t_] =` ... to `ma[t_] :=` ... (I think you intended `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`).
- There's a strange semicolon-like character at the end of `chromaticOvertones = Table[2^(i/12), {i, 0, 12}]；`. Replace it with a semicolon.

The definitions of `mA[t_]` and `s[t_]` declare a single argument `t_`, but they are called with `ma[t,fundamental]` and `s[t,440]`.

- In `ADSR[t,.05,.1,.2,1.5,1.0,0.7]*Sin[2*Pi*carrier*t + mA[t,fundamental] * Cos[2*Pi*t*1.5 fundamental]*1/3];`, change `mA[t,fundamental]` to `mA[t]`.
- In `Play[s[t, 400], {t, 0, dur}, SampleRate -> 8000]`, change `s[t, 400]` to `s[t]`.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't even notice that strange semicolon... It’s from the Chinese character set and looks similar to ;.....